# MySQL alter table issue

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench, alter-table

[image: snapshot of MySQL]

I was testing out the MySQL platform and ran into an
issue. When I right-clicked on the mlbleaderboard table and selected
alter table I do not see a breakdown of the column names, datatypes, and
default/expression under the "Comments:" block. Does
anybody see something in the snapshot[above] that could be causing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is your vertical screen size? MySQL Workbench needs a [minimum of 768 pixels](https://www.mysql.com/support/supportedplatforms/workbench.html). In that screenshot you apparently have not enough space to show the full table editor. Besides making the Workbench main window taller you can also close the output pane to get more room.

Comment: Oh wow yeah that's all I needed to do. This was my absolute time working with anything like this. Thanks

Comment: @JassiStacks If my answser helped you solve your question then please consider accepting it by activating the check mark below the vote buttons. This is how Stackoverflow reputation works. You can even upvote it, if you think it's worth it.